# Eclipse IDE will not allow me to create a New FXML Document for JavaFX. Errors out

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder, java-19

I am starting to learn JavaFX and SceneBuilder, and while I am installing SceneBuilder I am trying to add a new FXML document. When I right click on my project -> go to new -> other -> JavaFX folder -> New FXML document, if I click "Next" it does nothing. If I double click I get the following error:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
> org/eclipse/jface/databinding/swt/WidgetProperties

The following is the error in the error log and the stack trace:

```
Message: Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/databinding/swt/WidgetProperties
    at org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui.wizards.AbstractJDTElementPage.createControl(AbstractJDTElementPage.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1235)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.lambda$3(WizardDialog.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardSelectionPage.advanceToNextPageOrFinish(NewWizardSelectionPage.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardNewPage.lambda$0(NewWizardNewPage.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1542)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.WidgetProperties cannot be found by org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui_3.8.0.202204150904
    ... 67 more
```

I am on the newest version of Java, Exclipse, JavaFX, and SceneBuilder.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.